# Best approach for XML parsing on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've familiarized myself with the NSXMLParser from the iPhone SDK but I find the event-driven nature of it awkward for my purposes. I just want to extract some element values but this concept of having to handle the startElement, foundCharacters, and endElement seems like more work than it really should be. Am I just looking at this the wrong way or is there a simpler tree/DOM-based way of working with XML in the iPhone SDK?

If the advice is to just work with NSXMLParser, are there certain design patterns I can use to keep my code from having 5 levels of nested ifs in the startElement method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on the iPhone, using tree-based parsing can be a prohibitive memory hog. Trust me, I've been there, and I've tried many different approaches over the last five months of development of my main iPhone application. Tree-based parsing works fine until you download someone's comment stream containing 400 very long comments, clocking in at about 600KB of raw data. Quite aside from the size of the resultant XML tree, the memory allocated internally while creating that tree can be enormous.

I wound up creating a variant of NSXMLParser which pulls data in from a supplied NSInputStream rather than using a single chunk of data, and which passes only 1KB at a time into libxml for handling (NSXMLParser uses libxml too, but passes 100% of the data in one go).

The source code is available [on github](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/tree/master) (look in the StreamingXMLParser folder). You'll also find a delegate superclass in there; for most parsing needs you can subclass AQXMLParserDelegate and implement `-start[Element]WithAttributes: (NSDictionary *) attrs` and `-end[Element]` in your subclass. These methods will be called for you as start & end tags are discovered, and inside the end tag you can use `self.characters` to access the content characters or CDATA of the element.

For more on the relative memory footprints of the different parsers (albeit on the Mac, not the iPhone) see my original blog post [here](http://alanquatermain.net/post/93651539/aqxmlparser-big-memory-win) and the followup on NSXMLDocument [here](http://alanquatermain.net/post/93664991/aqxmlparser-test-redux).

Comment: Thanks this is useful info. I ended up adopting the startElement, foundCharacters, endElement pattern and it wasn't too bad but yeah now I'm noticing that NSXMLParser initWithContentsOfURL seems to download the whole document and leave it in memory as opposed to streaming it - like you pointed out. Which is kinda surprising since there's no reason you need access to the whole document when you're using an event-based parsing approach. I'll look into StreamingXMLParser.

Comment: Ok more investigation. Now I'm noticing that the memory footprint is moreso due to the URL download than the actual parsing. Am I doing an async download but it doens't seem to be releasing the already-received data chunks.

Comment: Yeah, the NSURLConnection stuff allocates a fair bit of memory internally while its doing things— and if you're using SSL there's ~1MB extra allocated for the encryption pipeline. I wound up writing my own wrapper around CFHTTPMessageRef and using that to get a stream to feed the parser; that's in the same github repository, in the HTTPMessage subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code snippet, that uses [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), [Matt Gallagher's libxml2 wrappers](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) and [Ben Copsey's ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest-CFNetwork-wrapper-for-HTTP-requests) to parse an XML document.

The `nodes` instance of type `NSArray*` will contain `NSDictionary*` objects that you can parse recursively to get the data you want.

Or, if you know the scheme of your XML document, you can write an [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp) query to get you to a `nodeContent` or `nodeAttribute` value directly.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"];
[request start];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSData *response = [request responseData];
    NSLog(@"Root node: %@", [[self query:@"//" withResponse:response] description]);
}
else 
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"kHTTPRequestFailed" reason:@"Request failed!" userInfo:nil];
[request release];

...

- (id) query:(NSString *)xpathQuery withResponse:(NSData *)respData {
    NSArray *nodes = PerformXMLXPathQuery(respData, xpathQuery);
    if (nodes != nil)
        return nodes;
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repurposing the code from Seismic XML provides a very good API that creates NSObject subclasses from XML.

> If the advice is to just work with NSXMLParser, are there certain design patterns I can use to keep my code from having 5 levels of nested ifs in the startElement method?

I depends on what you are trying to do. You could put your element names in a dictionary and take action based on the relevant object in a dictionary - this is effectively what SeismicXML does.