# Want to share a MGTwitterEngine iPhone Xcode skeleton project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter, project, sample

Anyone want to share an Xcode project that has MGTwitterEngine in it? Mine won't compile. Are there certain project settings to set? I just made a stock tab bar app for iPhone and added the MGTwitterEngine files. Tons of compiler errors. What am I missing?

Comment: You should give some of the compiler errors in your question. Otherwise this seems plz-send-teh-codez worthy.

Comment: It is "please send the code". Actually it's not code, I've got that. Just make it compile!

Comment: yes dear i have the code but i don't know how to share code with different users of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the library path right eventually. However, in the end, I got rid of the whole MGTwitterEngine thing and went with the TwitterHelper stuff that I noticed the folks from the Stanford iPhone class using. It uses the synchronous calls and it's not as full-featured. But it's lighter and I understand it better. I just use threading to counter the synchronicity. (Hey, wasn't that a song?!) Anyway, a little JSON code and it's all under control. Most of you are probably going to think I'm a noob but it just feels cleaner and easier to handle. I know there are plenty of good reasons to use MGTwitterEngine.

Bottom line is, even though I got it to work by getting the library path right, I don't even need to worry about any paths by adding the very small TwitterHelper stuff to my project. Seems more Mac-like than to have to go into too much tinkering (I can already hear the experts saying that setting paths is not too much but I absolutely detest the Project Settings dialog.)

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem. To get it to compile I added `"$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2"` to the Header Search Paths list. I also checked Recursive checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you're adding `"$SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2"` to header search paths in your Target settings and not just the Project.

Comment: Thanks, I think I had something close to that at one point. Anyway it worked eventually.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add

- libxml to Header Search Path ( should be something like /usr/library/libxml2 )

Comment: You shouldn't need to add -lxml2 to the compiler flags, since you're adding the library. But definitely the header files path.

Comment: I was hoping that was it but I actually had added libxml2.2dylib already. When I click on the "165 errors" indicator at the bottom right after compiling, the first error reported is:..

- (void)imageReceived:(NSImage *)image forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier

The error message is "error: expected ')' before 'NSImage'"

Comment: Did you add the lib to header search paths ?

Comment: Yeah, but maybe I did it wrong. I just put in "/usr/library/libxml2.2" (and versions thereof) in for a header path in the Project Settings.

Comment: thats wierd ..i will share my project once i get home

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add something that tripped me up.  You have to make sure the Target header search path is also set because it may override the default project search path headers.  If you are unable to find some header files that the path is definitely pointing to correctly in your project search path headers, then this is probably the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the libxml library. You need to add that to your linked frameworks. Here's a question that has a little more information, but that's the gist of it.

[Best approach for XML parsing on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842292/best-approach-for-xml-parsing-on-the-iphone)

Comment: I did add the libxml2.2dylib file to the project and I put "usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib" in for a header search path. I noticed there are whole other sets of these libs for the different platform/SDKs I have. I'm currently set for the iPhone Simulator platform and the iPhoneOS3.0 SDK. I assume that doesn't matter. The first error message in the list is: /MGTwitterLibXMLParser.h:10:30: error: libxml/xmlreader.h: No such file or directory

Comment: you should add libxml2.dylib, rather than 2.2. How are you adding it? You should use Target -> Info -> General -> "+" button. That should add it for all architectures. When adding the header file, be sure to check the "Recursive" checkbox.